# How do I summarise my pcap's parsed info into its different traffic types?

Tags: python, function, analysis, packet, dpkt

Hi there I am building a packet analysis tool. So far my code simply opens the pcap, parses it and closes the file. The code I have used has been adapted from the dpkt documentation. My pcap test files use different types of traffic (tcp, udp, igmp and http) and I need to be able to summarise each of these traffic flows, ideally being able to identify the traffic type adaptively as new ones appear. I need to include first and last timestamps for each type, a mean packet length and total number of packets. Sorry if it's a beginners question I'm just really struggling to use the dpkt documentation as I'm fairly new to python. At the moment I just have the output set to show the src and dst IP, packet length and timestamp. And help would be appreciated.

```
import dpkt
import datetime
import socket
import sys
import collections


def inet_string(inet):
    try:
        return socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET, inet)
    except ValueError:
        return socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, inet)

'''Function for printing the packet information'''
def print_packets(pcap):
    for ts, buf in pcap:
        # Print out the timestamp in UTC
        print('Timestamp: ', str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)))
        # Unpack the Ethernet frame
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        # Make sure the Ethernet data contains an IP packet
        if not isinstance(eth.data, dpkt.ip.IP):
            print('Non IP Packet type not supported %s\n' % eth.data.__class__.__name__)
            continue
        # Unpack the IP packet
        ip = eth.data
        # Unpack TCP
        tcp = ip.data
        # Print out the info
        print(f'{inet_string(ip.src)} -> {inet_string(ip.dst)}    Packet Length: {ip.len}')

def main():
    #Test Arguments
    #sys.argv.append('packets1.pcap')
    sys.argv.append('packets2.pcap')
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
        pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
        print_packets(pcap)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```